# 500 (Internal Server Error) in ajax data posting laravel 5.4

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel

hi i am trying to post some values on drop down change and fetch data form database on the base of that value and return back the ajax response .
like i want to get all branches of that specific company when i change company by drop-down, branches of that specif company displayed in drop down in a specific area 
**but i am facing 500 (Internal Server Error).** Always displays ***i am an error*** in console. My jQuery is

```
$(".select-company").dropdown({
    onChange: function (val) {

        var CSRF_TOKEN = $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content');
        var id=val;
        var urll = "promoplan/getcity";

            $.ajax
                ({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: urll,
                    data: { company_id: id, _token: CSRF_TOKEN },
                    cache: false,
                    success: function(html)
                    {
                    console.log(html);
                    //$("#regions").html(html);
                    },
                    error: function() 
                    {
                    console.log('i am an error');
                    }
                });
    }
});
```

My Route is

```
Route::post('promoplan/getcity','PromotionPlanController@getcity');
```

Comment: post controller part also

Comment: this is what i just writen in my **PromotionPlanController**  `public function getcity(){
        return Response::json("i am get city");
    }`

Comment: Inspect your browser and go to network then select XHR. Then you will get details about your error. May be it occurs for your PromotionPlanController.

Answer (score 2):

In your controller you have to incude following

```
use Response;
```

Comment: thanks aloat by adding this  line i got my  response,

Comment: i already given to you. how can i follow you so that i can get help, because i am new in laravel

Answer (score 0):

Can you try var `urll = "promoplan/getcity";` to `urll = "/promoplan/getcity";`